# Convert time stamp to 6 character string in Java

Tags: java, date, tostring

How can I convert a timestamp to a 6 character string. I tried to use base 36 which gave me a 8 character encoded string.

```
  long timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  System.out.println(Long.toString(timestamp, 36));
```

results in `"krouu1kv"`. (8 characters)

Ideally I need to generate an id(12 characters fixed) which consist of this encrypted timestamp(6 characters) and userid(6 characters).

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Are you absolutely sure what you want has anything remotely to do with encryption? What key and algorithm do you want to use for that encryption?

Comment: You can't do this AFAIK, not without also losing precision.

Comment: @luk2302 you are right updating the question(just to avoid confusion)

Comment: When you say "6 digits", do you mean 6 characters or 6 decimal digits (which would be impossible)?

Comment: @khelwood 6 characters

Comment: If you know the possible range of your timestamp you could reduce its size by subtracting the bottom of the range.

Comment: The maximum timestamp you can represent in base 36 with 6 characters is just after the year 1970

Comment: Nothing in your question has anything to do with encryption.

Comment: @khelwood could you give an example for subtracting the bottom of the range?

Comment: Create a Date for the earliest possible date you want to represent. Convert it to a long. Subtract that long from your `timestamp` long. Now you have a lower number that may require fewer characters to represent.

Comment: Encode (not en*crypt*) it in Base62 and you should be OK without truncating your timestamp

Comment: By the way, the terrible `Date` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. To get a count of seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC (1970-01-01T00:00Z), use: `long seconds = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();`. Or, for milliseconds: `long seconds = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();`.